# why the pixel set by setpixel returns a different value in getpixel ?

Tags: c#, getpixel, argb

here is my scenario:

I'm using  color.fromargb in C# to get a color out of an int upto 800  (which can be reversed by toargb).

I'm setting a certain pixel( eg: 0,0) in a bitmap to that color and saving it as jpg and when using getpixel to get that color and that int back, I receive a negative value which has puzzled me.
any thoughts and suggestion ?

Comment: Can you post some code of an issue?

Comment: You are probably overlooking *alpha*, the highest byte.  It is typically 255, producing a negative value when you read it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect two things are at play here.

Firstly JPEG is a lossy format so the number you put in might not be the exact number you get out, a true black is likely to become a gray.

Secondly, why do you get a negative when you start with a positive number? Well this is all down to the way `int` and `uint` and colours are represented in binary.

In RGB notation black has hex value `#ffffff` in ARGB it is `#ffffffff`.

`0xffffffff` in hex is 4,294,967,295 in decimal.

However an `int` is a signed type, meaning it is represented in  [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

If the highest bit in the bit in the number is set then you need to deduct -2,147,483,648; that is, hexadecimal 0x80000000.

So 0xffffffff becomes 2,147,483,647 - 2,147,483,648 = -1.

If your black became a slight gray like #ffeeeeee then its decimal value in two's complement notation would be -2,146,365,166.

Comment: thanks..it actually led me to use the metadata to include those integers in my bitmap